# compare python list with a string array column in Pyspark

Tags: python, arrays, list, dataframe, pyspark

I have a python list

```
my_list = ["AAA","BBB", "CCC"]
```

I have to compare this list with the array column in df

```
# dataframe dummy
df = spark.createDataFrame([('1A',    '3412asd','value-1',    ['XXX', 'YYY', 'AAA']),
('2B',  '2345tyu','value-2',    ['DDD', 'YFFFYY', 'GGG', '1']),
('3C',  '9800bvd',  'value-3',  ['AAA']),
 ('3C', '9800bvd',  'value-1',  ['AAA', 'YYY', 'CCCC'])],
('ID',  'Company_Id',   'value' ,'array_column'))

df.show()

+---+----------+-------+--------------------+
| ID|Company_Id|  value|      array_column  |
+---+----------+-------+--------------------+
| 1A|   3412asd|value-1|   [XXX, YYY, AAA]  |
| 2B|   2345tyu|value-2|[DDD, YFFFYY, GGG, 1]|
| 3C|   9800bvd|value-3|             [AAA]   |
| 3C|   9800bvd|value-1|  [AAA, YYY, CCCC]   |
+---+----------+-------+---------------------+
```

I am trying to filter the dataframe by checking if any element of `my_list` matches with any element in `array_column`

**Code I tried**

```
 final_df = df.filter(          
       F.arrays_overlap(F.col("array_column"),F.array(*[F.lit(x) for x in my_list])))
```

- I am getting the expected output but the arrays_overlap is returning `True` when both `my_list`and the `array_column` is `None`

**Cases to be included in the above filter:**

```
None, None => False # with the above code its returning True
None, SomeVal => False #But returning None
SomeValue, None => False #But returning None
```

explanation :

- if `my_list = [None, "AAA"]`  and array_column has a list `["BBB", None ]` - it should return False
- if `my_list = [None, "AAA"]`  and array_column has a list `["BBB", None "AAA"]` - it should return True
- Also if `my_list = None` and array_column has some list `["XXX","YY"]` then also it should return False also viceversa case should be False

Can anyone help me with this? How can i change the filter such that the above three cases return False ?

Comment: you mean in those cases `my_list = None` or `my_list = [None]` ?

Comment: if `my_list = [None, "AAA"] ` and array_column has a list `["BBB", None ]` - it should return False

Comment: Also if `my_list = None `and array_column has some list `["XXX","YY"]` then also it should return False also viceversa case should be False

Comment: the doc says: *"Collection function: returns true if the arrays contain any common non-null element; if not, returns null if both the arrays are non-empty and any of them contains a null element; returns false otherwise."* - you case falls into `returns null if both the arrays are non-empty and any of them contains a null element`

Comment: Can you share me the link @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/functions.html#collection-functions

Comment: Have you tried incorporating `array_except()` filtering out `None` values from your array prior to comparison? Maybe this would return the results you are expecting?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest - if `my_list = [None, "AAA"] ` and array_column has a list `["BBB", None "AAA"]` - it should return True But according to the documentation it would return None?

Comment: no, it should return `True` cause it complies `if the arrays contain any common non-null element` condition

Comment: How about substitution of None to a specific value temporarily using a `transform()` and return back to None after?